# Azure function ZIP Deployment using terraform

Tags: azure, function, terraform, azure-keyvault

I am looking to deploy Azure function by using Terraform, in the same way which is mentioned here in the Ms docs.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push

One of my need to store and Storage SAS key to Key Vault. I have seen some exmaple where we can below setting is used, but I can't use sas key without storing to Key Vault.

```
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_ZIP = "https://${azurerm_storage_account.this.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.this.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.this.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.this.sas}"
```

Any suggestion?

Thank you !

Comment: What do you have done and what error do you get?

Comment: One of my need to just use Key Vault to store the sas key, and sas key should not be visible in configuration.

Comment: Do you solve the problem or still work on it?

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you can use the Key Vault reference to get the secrets to the Azure Function like this:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

Or

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret;SecretVersion=ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
```

But this means only support system-assigned managed identities. So you need to enable the system-assigned managed identity and assign the right role of the Key Vault to it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?toc=/azure/azure-functions/toc.json) is more details.

Answer (score 0):

To get latest version of the secret, I remove the version number. So I used the URL:

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)
```

This always give me the latest SAS key from key vault.